# ES6: Unintuitive array element swapping using destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Trying to sort an array by swapping elements using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables):

The sorted array should be an ascending sequence of integers `[1, 2, ...]`.

```
// try to sort the array by swapping 
const a = [2, 1];
```

Why does the following piece of code not swap the elements as expected?

```
// Swap the '2' with the number at its final position.
[a[0], a[a[0]-1]] = [a[a[0]-1], a[0]];
console.log(a); // Result is still [2, 1]
```

However, switching the order of the elements to be swapped works as expected.

```
// Just changed the order of the two elements to be swapped
[a[a[0]-1], a[0]] = [a[0], a[a[0]-1]];
console.log(a); // Result is [1, 2] as expected
```

[Here's a nodejs REPL](https://repl.it/@r5d4/Destructuring-Assignment)

Comment: Can you please change your post so that it's actually in the form of a question, accompanied by some code, instead of a code block with a link and nothing else? (Remember to give ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) a read if you haven't yet, it's got some solid advice on posting to SO)

Comment: Here is a link to MDN which shows the proper way to swap using destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables

Comment: WTH are you using `a[0]-1]` as an index?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the values on the right of the = are cached first, then each assignment is executed in order from left to right.
If latter assignments depend on values of previous assignments, this will cause unintuitive results

Babel compiles the ES6 code into the following statements:

```
"use strict";

// try to sort the array by swapping elements
var a = [2, 1];

// does not work
var _ref = [a[a[0] - 1], a[0]];
a[0] = _ref[0];
a[a[0] - 1] = _ref[1];

console.log(a); // [2, 1]
```

The first example gives an unintuitive result because a[0] is modified before being accessed as a part of the second assignment.

Swapping the assignment order so a[0] is accessed before its value is modified yields the correct result.

```
// does work
var _ref2 = [a[0], a[a[0] - 1]];
a[a[0] - 1] = _ref2[0];
a[0] = _ref2[1];

console.log(a); // [1, 2]
```